# Intro Probability Question Help needed

Tags: probability

1. Assume that 30% of people who enter a hardware store will make a purchase. Eight people enter in a one-hour period.

(A)What is the probability that exactly three people will make a purchase?

So is it 3/8 = 0.375

(B)What is the probability that at least one person will make a purchase?

1/8= 0.125

-Am I doing this correct because it seems like the questions are too easy or I'm doing something wrong by not calculating something?

Comment: No those are not correct. Why would the probability of at least one person making a purchase be less than the probability of exactly three?

Comment: You aren't taking into account the 30% probability that customer makes a purchase in any way.  Think about what that has to do with the problem.

Comment: 8 people will enter but only 30% will buy so only 2.4 people buy something. How can I set it up a little confused

Comment: Each individual person has a 30% chance of buying. $2.4$ people can't buy something. That would be the average number of people that buy something if you carry this experiment many times.

Comment: Have you learned about the binomial distribution? This is a direct application.

Comment: If we have $n$ independent trials, each with probability $p$ of a success, then the binomial distribution is the way to go. If $X$ is the number of successes you observe, then your notes should say that the probability of $k$ successes is given by $$P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If eight customers are walking in and three make a purchase you'd need to consider the possibility that:

1,2,3 make a purchase, or

1,2,4 make the purchases or

1,2,5 make the purchases
...
6,7,8

The first answer is

$$\binom{8}{3} (0.3)^3(0.7)^5 $$

The second answer is $1 - P(0 \textrm{ purchases made})$
$$ 1 - (0.7) ^ 8 $$

Comment: Sometimes it's best to let OP work it out himself.

Comment: @Remy, OP is clearly lost and in danger with "seems to easy" and $3/8$. If I was on another planet, I'd want to know ASAP.

Comment: Jaslibra just wondering is it 1 - (0.7)^8 or just (0.7)^8

Comment: Hey if you can confirm my answers, for the first one I calculated 0.2541 and the second one 0.9424.

Answer (score 1):

I'll talk you through part B, then you can try part A on your own.

The only way it is not the case that at least one person makes a purchase is that no customer makes a purchase.  If the probability that a customer makes a purchase is $.3,$ the probability that he does not make a purchase is $1-.3=.7.$

Therefore, the probability that someone makes a purchase is $1-.7^8.$

The probability that none of the eight customers make a purchase is $.7^8.$ because the events are independent.  That is, one customer's making a purchase doesn't affect the probability of some other person's making a purchase. (It doesn't say this in the problem statement, but it's always assumed in these elementary probability problems.)  With independent events, the probability that two event both happen is the product of the probabilities of each event.

To do part A, try to follow the same kind of reasoning.  What has to happen for the conditions to be fulfilled?  There are two rules you use in these problems:

1. If A and B are mutually exclusive events (they can't both happen) then the probability that one or the other (or both) happens is the sum of their probabilities.
2. The probability that A and B both happen is the product of their probabilities, provided A and B are independent.

Comment: So the probability that atleast one customer will make a purchase is 1-.8^7? why do I have to check none of the 8 make a purchase which you show is .7^*

Comment: It's $1-0.7^8$, he made a typo.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  I meant 1-.7^8

Comment: Thanks man I see how these questions work now

Comment: Think nothing of it.  My pleasure.